# Error while executing free() saying "glibc detected double free or corruption"

Tags: c, malloc, free, glibc

i'm trying to run a program using an array that i allocated manually with malloc(). I free() this array at the end of my program but i keep getting an error saying `*** glibc detected *** ./test: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000002177010 ***`

Here is my main :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pthread_t t1, t2, t3;
    int i = 1;
    int k = 0;
    Client* clients;
    clients = (Client*) malloc((nbClients+1)*sizeof(Client));
    for (i = 1; i <= nbClients+1; i++)
    {
        printf("\n----TICKET%d----\n", i);
        clients[i].panier = (int*) malloc(nbArticles*sizeof(int));      
        achats(clients[i].panier, &clients[i].ticket);

        for (k = 0; k < nbArticles; k++)
        {
            printf("panier[%d] = %d\n", k, clients[i].panier[k]);

        }

        pthread_create(&t1, NULL, calcMACL, &clients[i]);

        //calcMQUAD(clients[i].panier, &clients[i].ticket);
        //calcMACL(clients[i].panier, &clients[i].ticket);
        //calcMCUBE(clients[i].panier, &clients[i].ticket);

        pthread_join(t1, NULL);
        //free(clients[i].panier);

    }

    free (clients);




    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing outside the bounds of the buffer you allocated, which possibly corrupts the malloc data structures resulting in the error you get. This is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The loop should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < nbClients+1; i++)
```

Remember, index starts from 0 in C.

Comment: lmaooo yes just saw it, sry i'm really tired i think
thank you it works now
but i always get the same values ? is it normal ? (i'm using a random int function, and it's always exactly the same)

Comment: I don't see any random number generation. You may have other problems in the code you haven't posted.

Comment: yes it's okay i corrected it (i did not put any seed), fanks

Answer (score 2):

When `free()` fails it is because of some memory corruption in your program, caused by bugs.

In this case, it is because the loop `for (i = 1; i <= nbClients+1; i++)` accesses the array out-of-bounds.

Comment: lmaooo yes just saw it, sry i'm really tired i think
thank you it works now
but i always get the same values ? is it normal ? (i'm using a random int function, and it's always exactly the same !)

Answer (score 1):

Indices in C start from zero. Last index of *clients* is *nbClients* + 1 - 1 which means that your loop guard is wrong. I would recommend to use a separate variable for the length of the dynamic array and a macro for memory allocation:

```
#define NEW_ARRAY(ptr, n) (ptr) = malloc((n) * sizeof (ptr)[0])

int clientsLen = nbClients + 1;
NEW_ARRAY(clients, clientsLen);
for (i = 0; i < clientsLen; i++)
   ...
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use that ugly macro. Please don't advise people to obfuscate their code. All you achieved with that macro is more bug potential, while at the same time, the code turned harder to read. Function-like macros is the very last resort, and when you use them, you must absolutely use an outer parenthesis around them.

Comment: @Lundin I don't want to do an error-prone size calculation every time I allocate memory. If the type of or the name of the pointer changes I also don't want to update the code in more places than necessary. With "function-like macros is the very last resort" I fully agree. NEW_ARRAY is to be used as a statement, therefor the lack of outer parentheses.